# Why is this example not endian-dependent?

Tags: c++, endianness

https://cppquiz.org/quiz/question/249

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = '0';
    char const &b = a;
    cout << b;
    a++;
    cout << b;
}
```

I know the answer here but wonder why this is not implementation defined... i.e. machine-dependent?

What if you run on this code on one big-endian machine, then recompile and run it on a little-endian machine?

When you try to print the literal character '\0' in cout, it will not print a '0'.

Comment: Do you see any code that's memory layout dependent? In general it is rare to run into these kind of issues unless you are serializing or deserializing. Which is usually best left to libraries (or low level hardware access)

Comment: Why would endian-ness play a roll? I see no bit manipulations, no looking at the bytes of an object.

Comment: why do you expect this to depend on endianess? What difference would it make?

Comment: What I mean is that you cast the int variable to a char.

Comment: You should not write code like this anyway.

Comment: Why do they ask the question then?

Comment: Because "this is not good C++" is also an answer.

Comment: You should include the output in the question (and also what other output you expect). Its a trick question, and your question is about a different aspect

Comment: @DecafSux *"you cast the int variable to a char"* -- Yes, you do. The cast preserves value; it is not dependent on the binary representation.

Comment: I agree that the code is utter sheit. But I wonder why it's not memory-layout dependent.

Comment: eg consider what output you get when you print `a` after the increment https://godbolt.org/z/5qd5Eo41h

Comment: "But I wonder why it's not memory-layout dependent" why would it be?

Comment: If you cast it to a char* instead it will be

Comment: As far as I can tell its undefined behavior and the program can output anything. So endianess doesn't matter anymore

Comment: ah.. saw the answer now from JaMiT. Thanks

Comment: @PepijnKramer That was what I was thinking as well. But according to cppquiz it's not.

Comment: @DecafSux Avoid using most of those sites, they are not a good source.

Comment: Right I see... the reference isn't modified. So it is const correct. But pff still code I would walk away from. In the end it is the responsibility of a programmer to also write code that is readable and has no surprises (and should not take to much time to understand)

Comment: @user12002570 In a way I agree. But in another way it actually teaches you how the compiler sees the language. I would never write code like this for sure. C++ is complex and I guess this site highlights that aspect pretty well.

Comment: Endianness primarily relates to how multi-byte data is stored in memory (e.g., byte order), but it doesn't affect the interpretation of individual character literals or values. For single-byte data types, like char, endianness is generally not a concern.

Comment: Explanation on the site seems clear to me... `b` bound to a temporary (which has initial `a` as value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not binding the reference to the first byte of `a`, instead the right-hand side is evaluated to `int&` holding `0x30`, this reference is converted to a temporary `char` `0x30` and the reference is bound to this temporay char, not to `a`.

At no point did the memory layout matter. Casting of `int` to `char` is defined as `mod 256` (assuming unsigned 8bit `char`). It is up to the implementation to ensure that happens.

Sure, on non-8bit naive big-endian architecture the cast might involve shifting the highest byte to the lowest position in order to use the register as true `char` but those are technical details for someone else to deal with.

Comment: Thanks. Still for this example I would just make a flat copy of the value instead of having a const reference. I guess it just teaches how the compiler interprets a const reference.

Comment: I would like to point out that it's not the same case for objects.

Comment: @DecafSux What do you mean the same case of what?

Comment: @DecafSux it is actually supposed to give you an insight on rvalues and implict conversions. Remove the `const` modifier to see a compile error. Then change the lvalue reference specifier `&`  on `b` to rvalue reference specifier `&&` and run the program again.

Answer (score 1):

Your binding `b` to a temporary copy of `a` (or rather, the low order byte of `a`), not to `a` itself. The implicit conversion of `a` to `char` creates a temporary.

If you want to see changes due to byte order, you need to work with pointers (using the appropriate cast and dereference operators):

```
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    int                 a = '0';
    char const*         b = reinterpret_cast<char const*>( &a );
    std::cout << *b << std::endl;
    ++ a;
    std::cout << *b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```